# Installed rtl8812au-dkms for DWA-182 driver but driver not detected

Tags: drivers, apt, ubuntu-drivers

As the title says...

I executed

```
sudo apt-get install rtl8812au-dkms
```

or something similar, and it didn't work. Then, I got it from a git repository, performed 'make' and a series of other commands and it's not reading the adapter still.

Output of lsbusb, showing that my adapter is connected:

```
Bus 008 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 007 Device 002: ID 04ca:0050 Lite-On Technology Corp. USB Multimedia Keyboard
Bus 007 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 006 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 005 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 003: ID 048d:8297 Integrated Technology Express, Inc. ITE Device(8595)
Bus 003 Device 005: ID 2001:3315 D-Link Corp. D-Link Wireless Adapter
Bus 003 Device 002: ID 046d:c083 Logitech, Inc. G403 Prodigy Gaming Mouse
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

Any help is appreciated!

The output of dkms status

```
rtl8812au, 4.3.8.12175.20140902+dfsg, 5.4.0-42-generic, x86_64: installed
```

so I have managed to remove both instances of the drivers, and reinstalled this, yet the driver is still not read.

```
T:  Bus=01 Lev=01 Prnt=01 Port=00 Cnt=01 Dev#=  3 Spd=480 MxCh= 0
D:  Ver= 2.00 Cls=00(>ifc ) Sub=00 Prot=00 MxPS=64 #Cfgs=  1
P:  Vendor=2001 ProdID=3315 Rev=00.00
S:  Manufacturer=Realtek
S:  Product=D-Link Wireless Adapter
S:  SerialNumber=123456
C:  #Ifs= 1 Cfg#= 1 Atr=80 MxPwr=500mA
I:  If#=0x0 Alt= 0 #EPs= 5 Cls=ff(vend.) Sub=ff Prot=ff Driver=(none)
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `lsusb` terminal command.

Comment: Bus 003 Device 005: ID 2001:3315 D-Link Corp. D-Link Wireless Adapter is the adapter

Comment: And what is the OS? Is Secure Boot disabled?

Comment: Ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS, and as for the Secure Boot I'll check BIOS and get back to you!

Comment: Secure Boot is in fact disabled. Since I'm using a Gigabyte X570 board enabling CSM disabled Secure Boot

Comment: Please add output of `usb-devices | '/3315/' RS=`

Comment: @Pilot6 bash: /3315/: No such file or directory

Comment: Oh, a typo `usb-devices | awk '/3315/' RS=`

Comment: update in the main post

Comment: This means this driver doesn't support this adapter. You can add to the source or find another one.

Comment: Thanks for your help! I don't suppose you know of any drivers that do work with this? Perhaps if I can use some sort of Wine + windows drivers mix?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For those who will come after me, it turns out that the repository simply doesn't support DWA-182 for some reason. However, not all hope is lost. For kernel version `5.4.0-54-generic` and `Ubuntu 20.04` the solution is to use a different repository. Executing below;

```
sudo apt-get install -y dkms git
git clone https://github.com/morrownr/8812au
cd 8812au
sudo ./install-driver.sh
```

will make a RealTek RTL8812AU Chipset card work. Cheers!